# What can generate a larger gravitational fiel than the earth?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

From what I know of gravitational fields and our earth gravity always repel objects and any mass. But I was wandering if there were forces that can oppose the earth gravitational force.

Comment: "repel"? I thought that gravity was famous for attracting.

Comment: Rockets oppose the Earth's gravitational force.

Comment: Earth’s gravity attracts, not repels.

Comment: The body of your question doesn't seem to have much to do with its title. Whenever you lift something you are opposing the Earth's gravitational field.

Comment: I suppose another question that could be asked is, do we have technological means of producing gravitational fields stronger than the Earth's own gravitational field (i.e. not using cosmic objects like the Sun or other planets). And working in a reference frame fixed to the Earth (so no centrifuges or other high-acceleration environments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gravitational force is attractive in nature so it always attracts. The Earths gravity also attracts other object towards it. Gravity is directly proportional to the masses of the objects. So, anything that has more mass than the earth  has more gravitational field and hence stronger force of gravity.

As for the forces that can oppose gravity, there are many of them. Gravity is one of the weakest fundamental force as its effect is almost nothing for larger distance or less mass. You oppose gravity by walking(reaction force), holding mobile above ground(force exerted by muscles), rocket(force or pressure due to expansion of burning fuel) etc.

But for an object with very large mass(big stars, black holes), the gravity can be a trillion times greater than that of earth or maybe even more.

Answer (score 1):

Any body more massive than earth generates a more powerful gravitation field. This includes the sun, Jupiter, Saturn, other large planets, and other stars.

There is nothing we know of that repels the gravitation field. The magnetic field and electric field can be repulsive but not necessarily to massive bodies.